# Linux - RHEL 8.3 - Unable to start PostgreSQL 13 service - Cannot open shared object library

Tags: postgresql, rhel

Trying to setup PostgreSQL 13 on RHEL 8.3 Linux Server. Attempting to start the service after following the installation steps outlined in the PostgreSQL documentation including the initdb I get the below output when running `journalctl -xe` after trying `systemctl start postgresql-13`:

```
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-13.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit postgresql-13.service has begun starting up.
Mar 19 23:53:11 host.local postmaster[485386]: 2021-03-19 23:53:11.209 AWST [485386] FATAL:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-13/lib/timescaledb.so": /usr/pgsql-13/lib/timescaledb.so: cannot open shared object file: Operation not permitted
Mar 19 23:53:11 host.local postmaster[485386]: 2021-03-19 23:53:11.209 AWST [485386] LOG:  database system is shut down
Mar 19 23:53:11 host.local systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 19 23:53:11 host.local systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- The unit postgresql-13.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 23:53:11 host.local systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 13 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-13.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit postgresql-13.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

Digging around I thought okay, let's check my `ldconfig` conf files. But they correctly reference the libraries mentioned in the output. So I tried manually running `ldconfig` with `-v` to see the output.

```
[root@host ~]# ldconfig -n -v /usr/pgsql-13/lib
/usr/pgsql-13/lib:
        libpqwalreceiver.so -> libpqwalreceiver.so
        libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.13
        libpgtypes.so.3 -> libpgtypes.so.3.13
        libecpg_compat.so.3 -> libecpg_compat.so.3.13
        libecpg.so.6 -> libecpg.so.6.13
```

However, an `ls -l /usr/pgsql-13/lib` shows a much larger output of libraries, leaving me to wonder what am I missing? I have tried changing permissions within the directory but that made no change so reverted the permissions:

```
total 13784
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20440 Feb 11 09:43 adminpack.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   36976 Feb 11 09:43 amcheck.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7680 Feb 11 09:43 auth_delay.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16256 Feb 11 09:43 auto_explain.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11896 Feb 11 09:43 autoinc.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       6 Feb 11 09:43 bitcode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   29504 Feb 11 09:43 bloom.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   32672 Feb 11 09:43 btree_gin.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   92872 Feb 11 09:43 btree_gist.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16128 Feb 11 09:43 citext.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   50568 Feb 11 09:43 cube.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16088 Feb 11 09:43 cyrillic_and_mic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   50224 Feb 11 09:43 dblink.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11848 Feb 11 09:43 dict_int.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  497200 Feb 11 09:43 dict_snowball.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11984 Feb 11 09:43 dict_xsyn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7696 Feb 11 09:43 earthdistance.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11792 Feb 11 09:43 euc2004_sjis2004.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7688 Feb 11 09:43 euc_cn_and_mic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15952 Feb 11 09:43 euc_jp_and_sjis.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7704 Feb 11 09:43 euc_kr_and_mic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16512 Feb 11 09:43 euc_tw_and_big5.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   24736 Feb 11 09:43 file_fdw.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   28960 Feb 11 09:43 fuzzystrmatch.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11680 Feb 11 09:43 hstore_plperl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   67120 Feb 11 09:43 hstore.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11888 Feb 11 09:43 insert_username.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   54640 Feb 11 09:43 _int.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  102720 Feb 11 09:43 isn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15808 Feb 11 09:43 jsonb_plperl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11864 Feb 11 09:43 latin2_and_win1250.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11816 Feb 11 09:43 latin_and_mic.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  727708 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101788 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg_compat.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg_compat.so -> libecpg_compat.so.3.13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg_compat.so.3 -> libecpg_compat.so.3.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   38320 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg_compat.so.3.13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg.so -> libecpg.so.6.13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg.so.6 -> libecpg.so.6.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  101288 Feb 11 09:43 libecpg.so.6.13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1310988 Feb 11 09:43 libpgcommon.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1306378 Feb 11 09:43 libpgcommon_shlib.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  624890 Feb 11 09:43 libpgfeutils.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  702572 Feb 11 09:43 libpgport.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  701762 Feb 11 09:43 libpgport_shlib.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  458268 Feb 11 09:43 libpgtypes.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Feb 11 09:43 libpgtypes.so -> libpgtypes.so.3.13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Feb 11 09:43 libpgtypes.so.3 -> libpgtypes.so.3.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   83704 Feb 11 09:43 libpgtypes.so.3.13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1762742 Feb 11 09:43 libpq.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 11 09:43 libpq.so -> libpq.so.5.13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 11 09:43 libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  338992 Feb 11 09:43 libpq.so.5.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   25136 Feb 11 09:43 libpqwalreceiver.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11832 Feb 11 09:43 lo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   63000 Feb 11 09:43 ltree.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11864 Feb 11 09:43 moddatetime.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   45928 Feb 11 09:43 pageinspect.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11848 Feb 11 09:43 passwordcheck.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11872 Feb 11 09:43 pg_buffercache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  139552 Feb 11 09:43 pgcrypto.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7720 Feb 11 09:43 pg_freespacemap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20592 Feb 11 09:43 pgoutput.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   29440 Feb 11 09:43 pg_prewarm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16144 Feb 11 09:43 pgrowlocks.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   45520 Feb 11 09:43 pg_stat_statements.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   29264 Feb 11 09:43 pgstattuple.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   54608 Feb 11 09:43 pg_trgm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20440 Feb 11 09:43 pg_visibility.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   25224 Feb 11 09:43 pgxml.so
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      31 Mar 18 22:32 pgxs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      86 Mar 18 22:32 pkgconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  200640 Feb 11 09:43 plpgsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  113888 Feb 11 09:43 postgres_fdw.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20224 Feb 11 09:43 refint.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   38008 Feb 11 09:43 seg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   71264 Feb 11 09:43 sepgsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20528 Feb 11 09:43 sslinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   24536 Feb 11 09:43 tablefunc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11872 Feb 11 09:43 tcn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16264 Feb 11 09:43 test_decoding.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  618784 Mar 19 09:12 timescaledb-2.1.0.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   52520 Mar 19 10:11 timescaledb.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  605640 Mar 19 09:12 timescaledb-tsl-2.1.0.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   12000 Feb 11 09:43 tsm_system_rows.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   12008 Feb 11 09:43 tsm_system_time.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16160 Feb 11 09:43 unaccent.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  122400 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_big5.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15912 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_cyrillic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  212488 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_euc2004.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   85536 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_euc_cn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  159264 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_euc_jp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  110120 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_euc_kr.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  208424 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_euc_tw.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  269888 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_gb18030.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  155168 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_gbk.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7720 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_iso8859_1.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   32336 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_iso8859.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  171552 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_johab.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  134664 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_sjis2004.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   89632 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_sjis.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  175648 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_uhc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   36424 Feb 11 09:43 utf8_and_win.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20752 Feb 11 09:43 uuid-ossp.so
```

I'm hoping for solutions, but would even appreciate just the next direction to take so that I may hopefully find the answer. Please note I've tried re-installing PostgreSQL and doing a new initdb etc to no success.

Comment: The issue is with `timescaledb`. Are you trying to install/run it?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I'm trying to install ApisCP - turns out it has a bootstrapper running in the background that kept re-installing Timescale whenever I was trying to troubleshoot postgres. I've been able to verify Postgres 13 works fine on RHEL 8.3. I'm now reviewing the ansible playbook to determine where they might be going wrong with the Timescale install, as I know Timescale <2.1 did not work with PG13.